# PDFs in HTML pages: is PDF.js safe for production?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, embedding

I'm researching ways to reliably view PDF files from with HTML pages on our site. I've found many references to [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), which looks really cool, but has almost zero documentation. Development appears to be active, but I can't tell if it's a realistic option for a production project right now.

The language on Github and Mozilla is full of "experiment..." and "test..." but the project seems to have been around for long enough for there to be a stable version.

If the answer is yes, is there any documentation anywhere?

Edit: I have no idea why this was closed with 6 upvotes, a completely answerable question, and no "unconstructive debate" whatsoever.

Comment: There are some other options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html